# Google NaCl with Qt on Windows

Tags: qt, google-nativeclient, qt4.7

I have a project which is using `Qt 4.7.4` version (also I can't rebuild it using `qt4.8` or `qt5` – there are a lot of errors appears, project is big and not mine so fixing issues would be even harder than erasing the whole code and write new code). So I need to make this project, well, working on NativeClient.

Is it even possible? I use Windows and Visual Studio, I was trying to google instructions about qt+nacl on Windows but just can’t find nothing.

Also which `pepper` version should I use if it depends on it?

Comment: You might be better off using emscripten, but it won't work regardless, too much functionality is missing in both ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Windows

The Qt-Nacl is not support, for now, in Windows.

By the way, here is the github repository dedicated for it -> https://github.com/msorvig/qt5-qtbase-nacl

In the file *nacl-readme* it is written :

> [...] Windows is not supported as a host platform.

### Linux

If you want to compile in Linux, I have made a script that will compile Qt5.4 with NaCl with all the dependencies needed.

https://gist.github.com/theshadowx/438297ac465874a5e226

I also made a video that will show the different steps and a showCase at the end :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2pMv1Svtqw

Comment: but hey, problem is not actual for me right now, so. but maybe it would help to others

Answer (score 3):

Is your qt build supporting native client?
Please check out [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_Google_Native_Client)

Comment: Yeah I already read it. Well, no I just got windows builded qt. Do you know where I can get 4.7.4-nacl qt?

Comment: You have to build it by your own as said in the article.

Comment: well, yeah I understood. But there is `qt5nacl` stuff. Is there `qt4.7.4-nacl` thing?

Comment: I think there is not.